# extjs 3 combo-box lable width and input field width

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-deployment, extjs3

I need to get combo-box label to a one line. I'm using **extjs3**.

**Code** :

```
var orq_type_button= new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        id:'testa',
        fieldLabel: 'Organization Type',
        editable:false,
        emptyText:'Empty',
        selectOnFocus:true,
        forceSelection: true,
        allowBlank: false,
        width: 350,
        labelWidth: 330,
    });

var assignConfig_window_formPanal = new Ext.form.FormPanel  ({
    id:'assignConfig_window_formPanal',
    frame:true,
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    height:110,
    buttonAlign:'center',
    items: [orq_type_button],
    buttons: [ {text: 'Save'} ,
               {text: 'Cancel',
                handler  : function() { 
                    assignConfig_window.hide();
                                     }
               }
             ]
});
```

**Screenshot** :

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Increase the `labelWidth` or for dynamic sizing, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791661/autosizing-textfield-label-in-extjs)

Answer (score 0):

**labelWidth** is a property of FormPanel or FieldSet, not for combobox. Move it to your form panel so that it can work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use labelStyle config. Please check this link.

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?37686-Setting-a-combobox-fieldLabel-width-to-include-long-labels